# How to save and display a json/octet-stream response from a server in spring boot REST service?

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot

This is the code I'm using:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String fooResourceUrl = "server URI";

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    String auth = "username:password";
    byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encode(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")) );
    String authHeader = "Basic " + new String( encodedAuth );

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);

    restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor("username", "password"));
    ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(fooResourceUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: do you get any exceptions with this code?

Comment: you should replace with this  `Arrays.asList(new MediaType[]{MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM}));`

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:: Return the "result" only.